# Back Two Steps Activity Android

Tags: android, browser, twitter4j

Hi i m using [Twitter4j](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample) and theres an issue of back stack because when i loged in it open browser for verification and then create new activity and then we press back button it opens browser again.i want to remove that browser activity from stack just that one and its mystery for me how to do that.

A start's B And B starts C ,B is Browser i dont have any control of it . i just want to remove B from stack

Comment: Do you found solution? If yes than please post here answer... 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call finish() on the activity you want to remove from the stack.

Code would be like this:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
 finish();  // removes activity from stack
```

Comment: This will delete my activity which i want to preserve.

Comment: I want A start's B And B starts C ,B is Browser i dont have any control of it . i just want to remove B from stack

Comment: So you have Activity A that has a link to a website and that opens the user's default browser and then that browser opens up something in your activity?  I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 0):

Found it my self it was easy there are just Two flags to set .

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
```

and this will remove next activity after it finish the task .